# How to apply contour for all content in the document output?

Tags: fonts, renewcommand, contour

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[letter, total={5in, 10in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\contourlength{0.3pt}
\contournumber{15}%


\chapter{Chapter One}
Some plain text. Some variables $a,b,c,d$, some ideals $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{m}$ and some formula $$\int_0^{\frac{pi}{2}} \ln(\sin(x))=\frac{pi}{2}\ln(\frac{1}{2})$$ The contour effect should be applied for all of them.
\end{document}
```

I would like to find a way to apply \contour{black}{for all the content in a document}. If better, is there a way to apply only on plain texts? Then only on math mode? Then I am able to switch between and see which renders better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Like many other commands with arguments (e.g., `\emph{}`),`\contour` cannot contain any paragraph ends (i.e., a blank lines or the `\par` command, and other vertical skips). That will break any text more complex than a single paragraph.

For instance, you cannot use commands as `\section` inside contour that internally use these commands.

On the same sense, the command accept inline math mode (e.g. `\(1+1\)`), but not with display the command  math (e.g. `\[1+1\]`). (Note: use `of $$` for display mode is discouraged).

However, it seems possible to fool the command to accept text with display math enclosing it in a box like a `minipage`, `\parbox` or `\vbox.

Even inside this box `\par` cannot be used at all, but allow others commands like `\vskip`, so you can make fake paragraphs skips inside the box.

Example:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath,lipsum}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\newlength\myparskip
\setlength\myparskip{1em plus .1em minus .2em}
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{\myparskip} 
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{\myparskip}
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{\myparskip}
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{\myparskip}
\def\mypar{\vskip\myparskip}

\begin{document}

\contour{cyan}{\noindent\vbox{\noindent%
Some plain text. Some variables $a,b,c,d$, some ideals $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{m}$ and some formula $$\int_0^{\frac{pi}{2}} \ln(\sin(x))=\frac{pi}{2}\ln(\frac{1}{2})$$ The contour effect should be applied for all of them. 
\mypar
Anoter paragraph \lipsum[1][1-3] 
\mypar  
One more. \lipsum[2][1-3]}}
\end{document}
```

Therefore, this way `\contour` could include several paragraphs even with display math, but only in   single pages. I must say that I think that this approach is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

A PDF special could be applied directly to every page.

For example (old-style code; the hooks of current releases would probably be more efficient):

[image: pdf specials]

You can adjust the width of the stroke (here, `0.2 w`).

Close-up:

[image: detail]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath,lipsum}
\AtBeginDocument{\special{pdf:literal 1 j 1 J 0.3 w 2 Tr 0 0.8 0.8 RG}}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipout{\special{pdf:literal 1 j 1 J 0.3 w 2 Tr 0 0.8 0.8 RG}}
%===============================
\begin{document}

At the Cat and Dog, there was ...

Some plain text. Some variables $a,b,c,d$, some ideals $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{m}$ and some formula: 


\[
\int_0^{\frac{pi}{2}} \ln(\sin(x))=\frac{pi}{2}\ln(\frac{1}{2})
\]

 The contour effect should be applied for all of them. 

\par Another paragraph. \lipsum[1-3] 

\par One more. \lipsum[2-5]


\end{document}
```

Or apply the literals only to selected text:

```
  \special{pdf:literal q}%
  \special{pdf:literal 1 j 1 J 0.2 w 2 Tr 0.8 0 0.8 RG}
<< your text >>
\special{pdf:literal Q}
```